# jquery cookie - how to use cookies with a name other than remembered

Tags: html, jquery, regex, cookies

I have a saved cookie with the name `nodeinfo-tab1` associated with the tab menu item. I choose the 'edit' menu option and would like to see a menu tab item called `nodeedit-tab1`.

All cookies always have the first part of the name `nodeinfo`, e.g. `nodeinfo-tab2`, `nodeinfo-tab3`. When I enter the edition, I have the same menu, but the menu items have assigned classes with the first part of the name `nodeedit`, eg `nodeedit-tab2`, `nodeedit-tab3`.

In editing, the `tab-title` attribute has a value, for example, `tab-title="nodeedit-tab1"`. How can I display it using the remembered cookie `nodeinfo-tab1`?

Thank you in advance for your help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.tab").click(function() {
    var activeTabId = $(this).attr("tab-title");
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    $(".cont").slideUp();
    $("#" + activeTabId).slideDown();
    
    $.cookie('activeTab', activeTabId, {
      expires: 7
    });
  });
  
  var selectedID = $.cookie('activeTab');

  if (selectedID) {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(".cont").hide();
    $('a.tab[tab-title=' + selectedID + ']').addClass('active');
    $("#" + selectedID).show();
  } else {
    $('a.tab[tab-title=' + nodeinfo-tab1 + ']').addClass('active');
    $("#" + nodeinfo-tab1).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<div class="tabbed_area">
  <ul 
    <li><a href="#" tab-title="nodeinfo-tab1" class="tab active"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;TAB1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" tab-title="nodeinfo-tab2" class="tab"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;TAB2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" tab-title="nodeinfo-tab3" class="tab"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;TAB3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="nodeinfo-tab1" class="cont">
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
      <tr class="dark-edit">
        <td class="nodeinfo-section-title" width="40%" colspan="2" nowrap><b>Head</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tleft-edit" width="50%">TD1</td>
        <td class="tright-edit" width="50%" nowrap>TD2</td>
      </tr>
  </div>

  <div id="nodeinfo-tab2" class="cont">
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
      <tr class="dark-edit">
        <td class="nodeinfo-section-title" width="40%" colspan="2" nowrap><b>Head</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tleft-edit" width="50%">TD1</td>
        <td class="tright-edit" width="50%" nowrap>TD2</td>
      </tr>
  </div>

  <div id="nodeinfo-tab3" class="cont">
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
      <tr class="dark-edit">
        <td class="nodeinfo-section-title" width="40%" colspan="2" nowrap><b>Head</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tleft-edit" width="50%">TD1</td>
        <td class="tright-edit" width="50%" nowrap>TD2</td>
      </tr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe it would be a good idea to remember two cookies at once? If I click on the 'nodeinfo-tab1' menu, the cookies 'nodeinfo-tab1' and 'nodeedit-tab1' will be automatically saved. But how to do it from my jquery code?

Comment: Unfortunately your snippet doesn't run. Could you add the missing jQuery cookie lib?
Also, be careful, you are selecting all the page elements with the `active` class and removing the class for all items. What happens if you have other widgets in the page with an *active* class? Select the tab area first and then handle elements below. `$('.tabbed_area').each((i, tabbed_area) => {
  var $tabbed_area = $(tabbed_area), $tabs = $tabbed_area.find('.tab');
  $tabs.on('click', (tab, event) => { /* handle tab click. */ });
});`

Comment: doesn't it mean that I delete and add 'active' status only to the 'a.tab' element ? `$("a.tab").click(function() {`

Comment: Unfortunately no because `$('.active')` is starting from the document. This is why I propose you create the `$tabbed_area` var so that you can target all active tabs with `$tabbed_area.find('.tab.active').removeClass('.active')` and do the addClass with `$(tab).addClass('active')` inside the click handler I mentionned in the comment above.